# How to change date format d/m/Y to Y-m-d PHP

Tags: php

I want to keep date format d/m/Y (24/12/2013) in client side (users enter date in that format from JQuery date picker). But in server side I convert it to Y-m-d(2013-12-24) format.

To do that I wrote code in this way

```
$brithdate = explode('/', $_POST['brithday']);
$brithdateFormated = $brithdate[2] . "-" . $brithdate[1] . "-" . $brithdate[0];
```

Is this correct? or is there any easy way to do that

Comment: take a look at [strtotime](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) after strtotime use [date](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format it again

Comment: Duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php) and thousands of other questions

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use DateTime objects when you're working with dates and times. You can use  [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse the date string and then the [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to format it the way you want:

```
$str = '24/12/2013';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $str);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // => 2013-12-24
```

For a list of available formatting options, see the [documentation](http://php.net/date).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$birthdate= strtotime($_POST['brithday']);
$brithdateFormated = date("d/m/Y",$birthdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me.

```
$start_date='04/05/2018';
$convertedDate= DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $start_date)->format('Y-m-d');
```

> Note: The First parameter should be same as your $start_date with '/' also. If you put '-' there, then it will not perform the correct conversion.